# How to make random N-dimensions by using Numpy?

Tags: python, random, numpy

I'm currently trying to make N-dimensional matrix.

```
import numpy as np
fitness_landscape = np.random.uniform (0, 1, size = (N, 2., 2., 2., 2.))
```

In this code, I want to reduce the recursive 2 dimensions. For example, like the following array (though it doen not work):

```
import numpy as np
K = 4
fitness_landscape = np.random.uniform (0, 1, size = (N, 2. * K))
```

Is there ways that meet my needs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [9]: K = 5

In [10]: fitness_landscape = np.random.uniform (0, 1, size = (N,) + (2,) * K)

In [11]: fitness_landscape.shape
Out[11]: (3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: how do you print the In and out on your answers ?